Error on Airbyte using cdc incremental load with mariadb as source and duckdb as destination
I am using CDC incremental load from mariadb database to the duckdb as a destination. Since there is no any connector for mariadb, I have used mysql connector. There is not any issue during set up process. However while syncing, the process stops after some minutes throwing out the following error :
Cannot invoke "io.airbyte.protocol.models.AirbyteGlobalState.getStreamStates()" because the return value of "io.airbyte.protocol.models.AirbyteStateMessage.getGlobal()" is null
and I am also getting following warning :
missing stats for job [job number]
I have checked the airbyte state message in the state table inside the internal postgresql. However, the state table is empty. Probably, the source is not emitting any state messages.
docker exec -ti airbyte-db psql -U docker -d airbyte

SELECT * FROM state;


The AirByte uses Debezium for processing the MySQL logs.
From Debezium, MariaDB is supported with MariaDB Connector/J requiring some supplemental configuration
{
  ...
  "connector.adapter": "mariadb",
  "database.protocol": "jdbc:mariadb",
  "database.jdbc.driver": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
}

